# How to make buttons (Corona SDK) from graphics with arbitrary shape?

Tags: events, button, touch, coronasdk

I have a profile of a mountain in my game and need Corona to be able to discern between the user pressing (touch event) on the mountain, and pressing on the valley in between the peaks (alpha channel used to create shape). It seems that Corona treats a display object in this sense as a rectangle, thus my need cannot be satisfied by any means I have found.

However, Corona physics functionality allows you to create complex polygons to mimic arbitrary shapes for collision handling, but I have found no similar method for buttons.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It's not automatic, but here's a solution you can try that involves a little setup and code.  Shouldn't be too difficult.

Test the location of the touch in your event listener by inspecting the `event.x` and `event.y` parameters.  You could make this efficient by creating a table that has values for the left-most x and right-most x value for each strip of, say 10 pixels from the top to the bottom of your object.  For example, consider this mountain:

[image]

Use the y coordinate of bottom of each light blue rectangle as the index into the table, and load the left x and right y values into that entry, e.g.:

```
hitTable[120] = {245,260}
hitTable[130] = {230,275}
```

and so on...

Then, in the touch event listener, force the `event.y` parameter to one of your table indices, either with a function or just testing to see which it's closest to.  Then, using that table entry, see if `event.x` is between the x coordinates you've specified for that y coordinate.  If not, just ignore the touch.

You can even build the table and assign it as a property of the image itself like this:

```
hitTable = {}
hitTable[120] = {245,260}
hitTable[130] = {230,275}
... and so on, then ...
myMountain.hitTable = hitTable
```

Once you've done that, you can access the table in the touch event listener as `event.target.hitTable`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion JeffK. However I was hoping to avoid a solution like this since it would mean manual labor to create the tables. The intention is to have somewhere along the lines of 40 mountain ranges like the one above with a substantial size in my app. Im afraid this might be another one of those features requests for Ansca. But Im sure theyve heard it before.

Answer (score 0):

Could you create the mountain peaks with a 90 degree angle tip. Then if you split the mountain peaks up and rotated them 45 degrees they would then fit into a square shape. Once you exported them each, you import them into Corona and then rotate them back 45 degrees.  I havent tested this but im imagining it might work :)

Comment: That could work. However I need flat sections as well (plains/ridges) so the problem remains.